# gpg does not ask for password

Tags: gpg

I encrypted one file with `gpg -c <file>` and closed the terminal. After a while, I tried to decrypt it with `gpg <file>` and it decrypted it, without asking for a password. Is that normal? How to guarantee that gpg will ask for a password, even in my same computer?

Comment: How long was it since you last entered you GnuPG password at that point? The `gpg-agent` caches it for 10 minutes by default (GnuPG 2.2).

Comment: Was gpg-agent running? If so it would have cached the credentials (just tested this on my Mac with gpg-agent in memory).

Answer (score 39):

This is normal, `gpg` now uses `gpg-agent` to manage private keys, and the agent caches keys for a certain amount of time (up to two hours by default, with a ten minute inactivity timeout).

To change the defaults, create or edit a file named `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, and use the following entries:

- `default-cache-ttl` specifies the amount of time a cache entry is kept after its last use, in seconds (600 by default);
- `max-cache-ttl` specifies the maximum amount of time a cache entry is kept, in seconds (7200 by default).

For example:

```
default-cache-ttl 300
max-cache-ttl 1200
```

will change these to 300s and 1200s respectively.

After changing these, you’ll need to reload the configuration:

```
gpgconf --reload all
```

Comment: If you just want to force `gpg` to forget its cached passwords and ask for a password again when you try to decrypt a file, see [my new answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/753082/114401).

Answer (score 19):

To make gpg >=2.1 always ask for a passphrase, run it with `gpg --pinentry-mode loopback`.

To make gpg >=2.2.7 always ask for a passphrase for `--symmetric` (`-c`) encryption, run it with `gpg --no-symkey-cache`.

Comment: `--no-symkey-cache` worked, but it's not on the help list of commands. Any idea why? Version is 2.2.19, Ubuntu 20-4.

Comment: @EvandroPomatti it is displayed via the `man` command underneath the `--symmetric` option, as mentioned by @anonymous

Answer (score 7):

GnuPG 2.2.15

> ```
>   --symmetric
>           -c  Encrypt with a symmetric cipher using a passphrase. The default sym-
>           metric cipher used is AES-128, but may be chosen with the  --cipher-algo
>           option.  This command may be combined with --sign (for a signed and sym-
>           metrically encrypted message), --encrypt (for  a  message  that  may  be
>           decrypted  via  a  secret  key or a passphrase), or --sign and --encrypt
>           together (for a signed message that may be decrypted via a secret key or
>           a  passphrase).  gpg caches the passphrase used for symmetric encryption
>           so that a decrypt operation may not require that the user needs to enter
>           the  passphrase.   The  option  --no-symkey-cache can be used to disable
>           this feature.
> ```

```bsh
# encrypt files
gpg -c --no-symkey-cache file.txt
# decrypt files
gpg --no-symkey-cache file.txt.gpg
```

with --no-symkey-cache option, it will not cache your password

Comment: @Kusalananda♦ I think my answer "guarantee that gpg will ask for a password", every time

Comment: Apologies, I missed the fact that the user mas doing symmetric encryption.

Comment: Note you will need [gpg 2.2.7](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2018q2/000424.html) or later.

Comment: This works but `--no-symkey-cache` doesn't show as an option in the help, I'm using 2.2.19.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding up... I use this simple function on my `.bashrc`, so that every time I want to force the password to be prompted again I can easily do so by just running `gpg-reload` from my terminal instead of waiting for the cache to be automatically cleared:

```
 gpg-reload(){
     pkill scdaemon
     pkill gpg-agent
     gpg-connect-agent /bye >/dev/null 2>&1
     gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye >/dev/null 2>&1
     gpgconf --reload gpg-agent
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It would be better to use `gpgconf --kill all` in place of those `kill -9` calls that you have. It's never a good idea to use `kill -9`, and if you really need to signal something based on its name, `pkill` would be a better tool.

Comment: was not aware of `--kill all` option, seems on gpgconf version 2.0.22, which I'm using right now, this option is not available....  Indeed, "kill -9" might be a bit rude... updating the response to use `pkill` as suggested, since its a better way to handle it :-) thx for the input!

Comment: How about just `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`?

Answer (score 1):

### Force `gpg` to forget all cached passwords

> How to guarantee that gpg will ask for a password, even in my same computer?

### Quick answer:

```bash
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

### Details:

If you goal is to just test to ensure that 1) a file is actually password-protected, and 2) you actually know and typed in your password correctly when you protected it, then you can force gpg to forget the cached password and request the decryption password again like this ([like @wisbucky said in this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395875/gpg-does-not-ask-for-password#comment1031296_543856)):

```bash
# force gpg to forget your temporarily cached passwords
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

Then, you can decrypt a file like this, and it will now ask for your password again!:

```bash
# decrypt a gpg-encrypted file
gpg myfile.txt.gpg
```

This assumes that `myfile.txt` was previously password-encrypted using `gpg`, like this:

```bash
# encrypt myfile.txt into myfile.txt.gpg
gpg -c myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your private key tied to a password? This is something you set at key creation time.

If not, GPG won't ask for a password, as none is required. It will simply rely on the key you provide.

And if so, should you have entered your password during another operation right before, GPG will not ask for this password again until a few minutes have passed.